# SwiftUI: why does ModifiedContent conform to `some View` function return type?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
// it compiles without any problems, regardless ModifiedContent is not a View
func modify(with viewModifier: some ViewModifier) -> some View {
    let content: ModifiedContent<Self, some ViewModifier> = modifier(viewModifier)
    return content
}
```

but if we write same in generic way, we got expected error message

```
func modify<V>(with viewModifier: some ViewModifier) -> V where V : View {
    let content: ModifiedContent<Self, some ViewModifier> = modifier(viewModifier)
    return content // error: Cannot convert return expression of type 
                   //       'ModifiedContent<Self, some ViewModifier>' to return type 'V'
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @robmayoff and @jrturton i finally figured out.
`ModifiedContent` conforms to `some View` because `ModifiedContent` conditionally conforms to `View`. We can make sure of this by watching definition of `ModifiedContent`. If we scroll down, we can see:

```
extension ModifiedContent : View where Content : View, Modifier : ViewModifier { ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's your first, working declaration:

> ```
> func modify(with viewModifier: some ViewModifier) -> some View
> ```

You used the `some` keyword twice in that function declaration. It is important to understand that `some` means **different things** in those two uses.

In the first use (`viewModifier: some ViewModifier`), the `some` keyword is “syntactic sugar” for a implicit, unnamed generic parameter. We can de-sugar the use of `some` there by replacing it with an explicit, named generic parameter, like this:

```
// Replace `some` in parameter position with an explicit generic parameter:
func modify<VM: ViewModifier>(with viewModifier: VM) -> some View
```

When you call that `modify` method, you as the caller choose a real type to replace the `VM` parameter. So you can call `modify` many times, with a different type to replace `VM` each time. The only constraint is the replacement type must always conform to the `ViewModifier` protocol.

The second use of `some` in your first function declaration (in `-> some View`) has a different meaning. It means the function will return a value whose type conforms to `View`, but the specific type is chosen by the body of the function. You as the function caller do **not** choose the type.

To summarize the differences:

- The `some` keyword in parameter position

  - represents an implicit, unnamed generic type parameter;
  - can be de-sugared to an explicit, named generic parameter without changing the function body;
  - is replaced by a type chosen by **the caller of the function**.
- The `some` keyword in return type position

  - represents a type known to conform to a protocol;
  - is a type chosen by **the body of the function**.

Now let's look at your second, broken function declaration:

> ```
> func modify<V>(with viewModifier: some ViewModifier) -> V where V : View
> ```

This is like your first function declaration, except that you have replaced the `some` in return type position with the generic parameter `V`.

The problem is that these don't mean the same things. As I explained above, a return type of `some View` means the **function body** chooses the actual type, but a generic parameter is always chosen by **the caller of the function**.

That's why you get the error when your function tries to `return content`. There's no guarantee that `content` has type `V`. Your function knows so little about type `V` (you only know it conforms to `View`) that there's no way for the function to even create a value of type `V` (because the `View` protocol doesn't have any `init` requirements).

You also have this comment on your first, working function declaration:

> ```
> // it compiles without any problems, regardless ModifiedContent is not a View
> ```

I assume you declared the `modify(withViewModifier:)` method in an `extension View`. That means `Self` conforms to `View`, so `ModifiedContent<Self, some ViewModifier>` conforms to `View`.

Comment: that's right, `modify(with viewModifier)` method is declared in an `extension View`, but i don't see conformance to View in ModifiedContent declaration: `@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@frozen public struct ModifiedContent<Content, Modifier> { ... } `

Comment: ModifiedContent conditionally conforms to `View` when "Content conforms to View and Modifier conforms to ViewModifier.", as stated at the bottom of the documentation page

Comment: Does Swift have such feature as conditional conformation? How can i declare some my custom struct to conditionally conform to View?

Comment: [Swift added conditional conformances](https://www.swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/) in 2018. You can find a discussion of the syntax and semantics in [SE-0142: Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md).

Comment: Thank you @robmayoff and jrturton for helping me to figure out what's going on. Now i clearly understand how it works and my question is solved

Answer (score 0):

`ModifiedContent` is a generic View so you can return it as opaque result type `some View`.
when returning `-> V where V : View` `ModifiedContent` has to match any `V` type where it is called from, which is not possible.

see as well: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-a-generic-type-as-the-functions-return-type/37666/2